# ASP.NET Core Web API is not working on IIS after publishing,But Working on my machine,

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, scheduled-tasks, quartz-scheduler, background-service

```
public class NotificationJob : IHostedService
{
    readonly ILogger<NotificationJob> _logger;

    public NotificationJob(ILogger<NotificationJob> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public async Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("Service started..!");

        await NotificationJob1();

        // ...
    }

    public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("Service stopped..!");
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    private async Task NotificationJob1()
    {
        var schedulerFactory = new StdSchedulerFactory();
        var scheduler = await schedulerFactory.GetScheduler();
        await scheduler.Start();

        // Define the job
        var job = JobBuilder.Create<BackgroundWorkerJob>()
            .WithIdentity("BackgroundWorkerJob", "DefaultGroup")
            .Build();

        // Define multiple triggers with different time intervals
        var triggers = new List<ITrigger>
        {
    //--------------------------------------- NOTIFICATION 0 ---------------------------------------- 

            TriggerBuilder.Create()
                .WithIdentity("BackgroundWorkerJobTrigger0", "DefaultGroup")
                .StartAt(DateBuilder.TodayAt(23,58,00)) // 2:19 PM Today
                .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x.WithIntervalInHours(24) // Repeat every 24 hours
                .RepeatForever())
                .Build(),
    //--------------------------------------- NOTIFICATION 1  ---------------------------------------- 
            TriggerBuilder.Create()
                .WithIdentity("BackgroundWorkerJobTrigger1", "DefaultGroup")
                .StartAt(DateBuilder.TodayAt(23,59,0)) // 6:30 PM Today
                .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x.WithIntervalInHours(24) // Repeat every 24 hours
                .RepeatForever())
                .Build(),

    //--------------------------------------- NOTIFICATION 2 ---------------------------------------- 
            TriggerBuilder.Create()
                .WithIdentity("BackgroundWorkerJobTrigger2", "DefaultGroup")
                .StartAt(DateBuilder.TodayAt(24,00, 0)) // 6:30 PM Today
                .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x.WithIntervalInHours(24) // Repeat every 24 hours
                .RepeatForever())
                .Build(),
    //--------------------------------------- NOTIFICATION 3 ---------------------------------------- 
            TriggerBuilder.Create()
                .WithIdentity("BackgroundWorkerJobTrigger3", "DefaultGroup")
                .StartAt(DateBuilder.TodayAt(15,32, 0)) // 6:30 PM Today
                .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x.WithIntervalInHours(24) // Repeat every 24 hours
                .RepeatForever())
                .Build(),
   

            // Add more triggers as needed
        };

        // Schedule the job with multiple triggers
        await scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, triggers, true); // 'true' means to replace existing triggers if any
    }
}
```

I have developed a background service schedule Task the above code is working on my machine. But after publishing to IIS server, it is not working and it is showing Swagger view also, code publish successfully fully.

But I am not getting the solution need experts help, will appreciate any help

Comment: Is the app set to with "Preload Enabled", if not, are you sending a ping to start your app? Try that and see if it works.

Comment: Yes "Preload Enabled = true";

Comment: oggy oggy - Can you open IIS and use the browse to invoke your app just to see if it is requiring a http request to start the app pool. If you have an enpoint  then hit it with swagger to make a request to make sure the app initializes.